# Transaction scope not working for Second transaction?

Tags: c#, database, web-services, transactionscope

In my application transaction scope is not working for second transaction..It is working fine for first transaction means if an exception is thrown first transactions got rollback but the second one didn't..

```
public string InsertRealm(string adminuser, string adminpassword, string CustomerCode, string CustomerName, string address, string email, string phone, string NoOfUsers, string ProductType)
{

  try 
  {
    using (Transactions.TransactionScope scope = new Transactions.TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required, new TimeSpan(2, 0, 0))) {
      string _strServer = sqlmethod.Read_config("deploymentSetting", "Server");
      string _strDatabase = sqlmethod.Read_config("deploymentSetting", "database");
      string _strUserid = sqlmethod.Read_config("deploymentSetting", "username");
      string _strPassword = sqlmethod.Read_config("deploymentSetting", "password");
      string constr_str = "server=" + _strServer + ";" + "database=" + _strDatabase + ";" + "uid=" + _strUserid + ";" + "pwd=" + _strPassword + ";";

      string _blankdbCrm = sqlmethod.Read_config("dbSettings", "blankcrmdbName");
      string userCountdb = sqlmethod.Read_config("dbSettings", "userCountdb");
      string bakRestorePath = sqlmethod.Read_config("dbSettings", "bakRestorePath");
      string mdfRestorePath = sqlmethod.Read_config("dbSettings", "mdfRestorePath");
      string ldfRestorePath = sqlmethod.Read_config("dbSettings", "ldfRestorePath");
      string _dbCrm = "";

      con.ConnectionString = constr_str;


      if (flag == "Yes") 
      {
        SqlCommand cmddb = new SqlCommand("crt_crm_db_details", con);
        cmddb.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmddb.CommandTimeout = 0;
        cmddb.Parameters.Add("@custname", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = ccode;
        cmddb.Parameters.Add("@blank_dbname", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = _blankdbCrm;
        cmddb.Parameters.Add("@blank_bakpath", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = bakRestorePath;
        cmddb.Parameters.Add("@blank_mdfpath", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = mdfRestorePath;
        cmddb.Parameters.Add("@blank_ldfpath", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = ldfRestorePath;
        cmddb.Parameters.Add("@usercnt", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = userCountdb;

        SqlParameter Typedb = new SqlParameter("@errorid", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
        Typedb.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
        Typedb.Value = null;
        Typedb.Size = 50;
        cmddb.Parameters.Add(Typedb);
        try 
        {
          con.Open();
          cmddb.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch (SqlException ee) 
        {
          VWLogger.LogMessage("Exception in crt_crm_db_details:", TraceEventType.Critical);
          VWLogger.LogMessage(ee, TraceEventType.Critical);
          return ee.Message;
          flag = ee.Errors(0).ToString();
        }
        con.Close();
      }

      if (flag == "Yes") 
      {
        Ramco.VW.Types.Message[] Msg_cust = null;
        try 
        {
          Msg_cust = client.addCustomer(ccode, cname, add1, "", mail);
        } 
        catch (SqlException ex)
        {
          VWLogger.LogMessage("Exception in addCustomer:", TraceEventType.Critical);
          VWLogger.LogMessage(ex, TraceEventType.Critical);
          return ex.Message;
          flag = ex.Errors(0).ToString();
        }
      }

      scope.Complete();
      return "Success";
    }

  } 
  catch (Exception ex) 
  {
    VWLogger.LogMessage("Exception in insertrealm:", TraceEventType.Critical);
    VWLogger.LogMessage(ex, TraceEventType.Critical);
    return ex.Message;
    throw new  CustomSoapException(CustomSoapException.ExceptionCode.AuthenticationException, ex.Message);
  }

}
```

Here `cmddb.ExecuteNonQuery()` got rollback but this one

```
Msg_cust = client.addCustomer(ccode, cname, add1, "", mail)
```

didn't get rollback Any suggestion?

EDIT:

```
<bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="UserNameTokenOverSSLBinding">
          <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential" />
        </binding>
        <binding name="BinaryCertTokenOverSSLBinding" closeTimeout="00:10:00" openTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:10:00">
          <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
            <message clientCredentialType="Certificate" />
          </security>
        </binding>
         <binding name="Vw30BasicHttpBinding" closeTimeout="00:10:00" openTimeout="00:10:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:10:00" maxBufferSize="65536" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536">
          <security>
            <transport clientCredentialType="None" />
            <message clientCredentialType="UserName" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
      <customBinding>
          <binding name="Vw30netTcpHABinding" closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:01:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00">
            <binaryMessageEncoding>
            <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384" maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
            </binaryMessageEncoding>
            <tcpTransport maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="99999998" connectionBufferSize="8192" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" channelInitializationTimeout="00:01:00" maxBufferSize="99999998" maxPendingConnections="20" maxOutputDelay="00:00:00.2000000" maxPendingAccepts="5" transferMode="Buffered" listenBacklog="20" portSharingEnabled="false" teredoEnabled="false">
            <connectionPoolSettings groupName="default" leaseTimeout="00:00:02" idleTimeout="00:02:00" maxOutboundConnectionsPerEndpoint="20" />
            </tcpTransport>
            </binding>
            <binding name="Vw30HttpHABinding">
            <textMessageEncoding />
            <httpTransport keepAliveEnabled="false">
            </httpTransport>
        </binding> 

        <binding name="UserNameTokenOverSSLOffloaderBinding">
          <textMessageEncoding messageVersion="Soap11" />
          <security authenticationMode="UserNameOverTransport">
            <secureConversationBootstrap />
          </security>
          <sslOffloadedHttpsTransport />
        </binding>
        <binding name="BinaryCertTokenOverSSLOffloaderBinding">
          <textMessageEncoding messageVersion="Soap11" />
          <security authenticationMode="UserNameOverTransport">
            <secureConversationBootstrap />
          </security>
          <sslOffloadedHttpsTransport />
        </binding>
      </customBinding>
      <netTcpBinding>
        <binding name="Vw30netTcpBinding" closeTimeout="00:05:00" openTimeout="00:05:00" receiveTimeout="00:05:00" sendTimeout="00:05:00" transactionFlow="false" transferMode="Buffered" transactionProtocol="OleTransactions" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" listenBacklog="10" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxBufferSize="65536" maxConnections="10" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384" maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
          <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="00:10:00" enabled="false" />
          <security mode="None">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None" protectionLevel="None" />
            <message clientCredentialType="None" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </netTcpBinding>
      <wsHttpBinding>
        <binding name="WSUserNameBinding" transactionFlow="true">
          <security>
            <transport clientCredentialType="None" />
            <message clientCredentialType="UserName" negotiateServiceCredential="false" establishSecurityContext="false" />
          </security>
        </binding>
        <binding name="WSBinaryCertBinding" transactionFlow="true">
          <security>
            <transport clientCredentialType="None" />
            <message clientCredentialType="Certificate" negotiateServiceCredential="false" establishSecurityContext="false" />
          </security>
        </binding>
        <binding name="WSUserNameReliableBinding" closeTimeout="00:10:00" openTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:10:00" transactionFlow="true">
          <reliableSession enabled="true" />
          <security>
            <transport clientCredentialType="None" />
            <message clientCredentialType="UserName" negotiateServiceCredential="false" />
          </security>
        </binding>
        <binding name="WsBinaryCertReliableBinding" transactionFlow="true">
          <reliableSession enabled="true" />
          <security>
            <transport clientCredentialType="None" />
            <message clientCredentialType="Certificate" negotiateServiceCredential="false" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
```

Comment: What is `client`?  It appears to be a web service call, in which case of course the transaction scope would not apply there.

Comment: But i have to rollback that also..what i have to do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What type of web service are you calling, and do you have control over it?

If this is a WCF web service, and you can edit it, then you can use **WCF Transaction Flow** to control the transaction from the client. Basically your TransactionScope would become a distributed transaction and carried over to the WCF web service. Your transaction would then properly roll back.

More info:

[Enabling Transaction Flow (MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733116.aspx)

[WCF Transaction Propagation (MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163432.aspx)

Comment: This. See also: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.services.webmethodattribute.transactionoption(v=VS.100).aspx

Comment: am new to this..how can i check whether mine is wcf webservice or asp.net webservice..it may be silly but no way

Comment: In my webconfig i have <wsHttpBinding> so mine is WCF Webservice right?

Comment: @bala3569 - Yes, `wsHttpBinding` would indicate that you are using a WCF SOAP based web service.

Comment: ok what i have to change in my webconfig..loot at my edit for my webconfig

Answer (score 0):

Transaction scope option Required specifies that the database access code would join the existing transaction if one exists. If you would like to commit your second transaction even if the first transaction rolls back, you have to specify RequiresNew.

Comment: @bala3569: My mistake! I thought you were talking about two transactions on the same database. You appear to be trying to implement distributed transactions.

Answer (score 0):

Web services happen on a different thread (at least) or possibly (even likely) on a different machine.  TransactionScope is thread-based.  It works based on the current transaction registered against the current thread.  Therefore, there's no way to use this facility when making the web service call.

Comment: But i have created proxy using .svc file and declared client like VWSecurityServicesClient client = new VWSecurityServicesClient("WSBinaryCert");

Comment: What does your having created a proxy have anything to do with it?  The code is still running in a different app domain (or host!).  Possibly the web service is running somewhere else on the internet.  (somewhat likely given that you're using certs)  How could it join in on the transaction on your machine?